# How to load images gracefully?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I want to know what are the ways to load images gracefully in a html website. I'm sure you know what I'm talking about. There is plenty of websites where images load slowly, slow down loading of the website core/content and make user experience really bad.

- I'm looking for ways which let the
  website core/content to be loaded
  first, and images to be loaded last.

I found this while searching:

[Javascript/jQuery preloader tutorial](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/how-to-create-an-awesome-image-preloader/)

[Working example of above tutorial](http://nettuts.s3.amazonaws.com/860_preloaderPlugin/index.html)

However, this seems to be cosmetic, it doesn't actually pre-load anything and doesn't boost performance either. It simply displays a .gif until the image has fully loaded.

- I've also seen websites where images
     first appear very croppy and their
     quality improves over a couple
     seconds. How is this done?

Comment: The images that appear to get better are "interlaced". It's a setting on the actual image file.

Comment: An **interlaced** JPEG will start loading blurry and sharpen as it completes.  A non-interlaced JPEG will load from top to bottom.  That is a file-save setting in the program that created the JPEG.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I've also seen websites where images first appear very croppy and their quality improves over a couple seconds. How is this done?

This happens when the images are interlaced. PNG files, among other types, can be interlaced.

[Wikipedia Link for Interlacing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interlacing_%28bitmaps%29)

This is done when the image is created/saved.

Answer (score 5):

It is called lazy loading.

There are a lot of results about it on [**google**](http://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ie=UTF-8&ion=1&nord=1#sclient=psy&hl=en&authuser=0&nord=1&site=webhp&source=hp&q=lazy%20loading%20jquery&pbx=1&oq=&aq=&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=&gs_upl=&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=74320bbe8d23f39f&ion=1&biw=1680&bih=965&ion=1&pf=p&pdl=500).